# Creating silverlight application am facing following error in my design part

Tags: c#-4.0

in Mainpage.xaml

> System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

error occurred how to solve it..

Comment: Actually am asking silverlight application design part error.. the object reference error is common but the showing  area is differ sry for not mention the page..

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be with the data binding. Are you using MVVM model?

Comment: no am using normal Visual studio 10. i need to add any external software to create Silverlight application?

Comment: no. you don't have to add anything extra. MVVM (Model, View, ViewModel) is the design pattern like MVC. I wanted to know how you are binding data to your controls.  are you directly assigning data to controls in the code behind  like Textbox1.Text="test"?

Comment: If its urgent for you, I can help only if see your code. give your Skype id, will ping you.